# Can I intercept all of the request from a specific electron browerwindow?

Tags: javascript, electron

I tried the following code:

```
win1.webContents.session.webRequest.onBeforeRequest((detail, callback) => {
    // All of the browserWindow's request will be canceled.
    callback({cancel: true})
})
```

The question is that I want to cancel the http request from `win1`, and the code above will take effect to all of the window.